# SSD cache, SRT, Raid 0 : speeding up my C drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid, cache

I have a Z97 rig and I'm interested in speeding up my disk drives.

This is my current setup:

1) 240GB SSD for main disk
2) 500GB hard drive for User Files
3) 120GB for photo editing (I move files here and then edit off of it).
4) 240GB SSD that I just got.

I'm interested in running a Raid 0 array with the 2 240GB SSD's and buying a 64GB SSD for SRT.

Is this overkill? What are your thoughts? I do know that this leaves my data open to getting destroyed in the Raid 0 array.

Comment: An SSD Raid is only useful when you move a lot of large files on them. For the OS it gives you very little benefits because the access time does not change. It may even be counterproductive because in Raid you may not have Trim support and that will degrade the write speed. Caching the HDD is useful though.

Comment: Fair enough. How would you go about designing a system with these drives?

Comment: I would use the #4 SSD  for virtual partitions. But that may be just me.